# use multiple Cognito Pool Client ids on the same Cognito Identity Pool for login

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito Identity Pool set up to use a Cognito user pool as a source of identity. Now, in my case the Cognito User Pool has 2 different client id, one for my mobile application and one for my website. In order to support login from both I need to add both client ids in the Authentication Providers settings but it seems that you can add only 1 client id at a time. Is there a way to configure Cognito Identity Pool to accept 2 different Cognito Pool client IDs?
I don't wanna use the same client id cause I need to do different user validations on user sign-up based on where the user came from (app or web) and the client id is the only parameter passed to my lambda that allows me to identify from where a user came from.

Answer (score 0):

From the Identity Pool [Cloudformation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-identitypool.html), it looks like you can provide a *list* of identity providers. A user pool identity provider is defined as the user pool ID plus the client ID. It seems like you should be able to specify two different ones with the same user pool ID and different client IDs. I *don't* know whether this is possible through the console.